# Avoid include guards in the case of multiple inheritance

Tags: c, include

I have an inheritance structure in a C program as follows:

`program.c` includes `support.h` and `utility.h`
`support.h` includes `core.h`
`utility.h` includes `core.h`

Since `core.h` includes both enums and typedefs, they are colliding in `program.c`. Both support and utility use prototypes that depend on the typedefs in `core.h`

Is there any way to structure this that avoids the use of include guards?

I have read theoretical opinions that [include files should not have other includes inside of them](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7728207) which of course would solve my problem. But I don't understand how to avoid that. If I have a prototype like `prune( TREES* t );` in `gardening.h` in a header file and the typedef `TREES` is located in a different header file `tree.h`, I don't really see how I can avoid including `tree.h` in `gardening.h`

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the program without include guards by including `"core.h"` before `"utility.h"` and/or `"support.h"` and not include `"core.h"` in either of there include files.

This is a convention that must be followed for the whole project, but requires the programmer to resolve all include file dependencies in every source file, which is tedious and error prone for large projects.  This becomes a maintenance nightmare when dependencies change with new versions of definitions, especially as the compiler error messages are less than obvious about where to get the missing definitions.

**program.c**:

```
#include <stdbool.h>  // needed by core.h, utility.h
#include <stdio.h>    // needed by utility.h
#include <stdlib.h>   // needed by support.h

#include "core.h"     // needed by support.h, utility.h
#include "support.h"
#include "utility.h"
...
```

**support.c**:

```
#include <stdbool.h>  // needed by core.h
#include <stdlib.h>   // needed by support.h

#include "core.h"     // needed by support.h
#include "support.h"
...
```

**utility.c**:

```
#include <stdbool.h>  // needed by core.h, utility.h
#include <stdio.h>    // needed by utility.h

#include "core.h"     // needed by utility.h
#include "utility.h"
...
```

I would recommended following a different convention: it is much  simpler and more reliable to ensure that all files include whatever include files are needed for the required definitions, including the include files themselves that should compile to empty object files.  Preventing multiple inclusions from producing errors for redundant definitions is done with include guards using a project wide convention to avoid name collisions.

Modern compilers are optimized for this convention and skip include files that have been parsed already whose contents is protected by a defined include guard.